Update Page Titles and Mobile Site to reflect the Site Name
In light of the update from Robert about The LEGO Group not having an issue with the site being called "LEGO Answers", we should update the following items to reflect this:

The home page <title> tag currently reads: "LEGO® - Stack Exchange" this should be updated to "LEGO® Answers - Stack Exchange"
The Mobile site header just reads: "LEGO®" this should be updated to "LEGO® Answers".

I assume that these changes will also update the FAQ pages to reflect the site name as well?


And I guess "Lego® Meta - Stack Exchange" needs to become "Lego® Answers Meta - Stack Exchange", too?

Yep, I guess so ;)

Someone appears to have fixed this, but I'm not sure who or how ;)

I updated the FAQ page myself.

Thank Rebecca Chernoff for putting in waaay too much effort and putting up with my nagging until this finally worked.

Will do: Thanks Rebecca :)

This was all Rebecca Chernoff's work, but someone needs to post an answer to herald this as being complete, neh? ♪

I suppose so, although I was happy to mark it as status complete :)
